# Windows Nodes disconnect from Jenkins master in Azure after multiple of 5 mins

Tags: azure, jenkins

We have created a Jenkins master in Azure.

When I connect a windows node (slave) to it using Launch agent from browser or by running the agent command from the command prompt, the node stays connected for just over 5 or 10 or 15 mins, then there is a Terminated message:

```
Jun 10, 2020 7:12:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Jun 10, 2020 7:12:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to total-control-jenkins.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com:5378
Jun 10, 2020 7:12:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Jun 10, 2020 7:12:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: 0d:ab:40:5d:2c:9e:77:28:31:5a:59:38:b5:1a:03:db
Jun 10, 2020 7:12:42 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Jun 10, 2020 7:18:03 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

The node attempts to reconnect, but this always fails.

We have tried changing `hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingIntervalSeconds` to 120
[System Properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m8Rk.png)
This made no difference

Any suggestions?

## Update

Solution: change the TCP parameters in the registry as described here:https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001416548-Dedicated-JNLP-agents-formerly-slaves-Troubleshooting-guide#7bwindows
and **restart** the machine. I'd already tried this, but didn't restart.

Comment: which machine did you add the registry entries on? the master or the agent?

Answer (score 0):

When you say *created a Jenkins master in Azure*, I assume that it's done by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/configure-on-linux-vm) Azure document. If that's the case, I recommend to double check if you have enabled cloud agents or not and if yes, is it ACI or VM or none and take action accordingly. Also, I recommend to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/scale-deployments-using-vm-agents) Azure document for configuring the agents and see if issue still persists. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097428/jenkins-vm-azure-agent-node-goes-offline-after-work-and-unable-to-start-back/61343163#61343163) related question might not directly help resolve your current issue but may be it would give you some insight regarding such node going offline issues.